# phpword generated file has different lineheight on mac and windows

Tags: php, windows, macos, docx, phpword

To open the docx file in mac I use the WORD Reader, where you can not edit the text, but at least open and read it. there, the content works fine. But when I open the file on Windows with Microsoft WORD, the lineheight is different and stretches the whole content.

Is it because of the Tables I am using? Do I have to define the lineheight?

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention table columns , width , height as in different places default values are different

```
    $PHPWord = new PHPWord();
    // document style orientation and margin 
    $sectionStyle = array('orientation' => 'landscape', 'marginLeft'=>600, 'marginRight'=>600, 'marginTop'=>600, 'marginBottom'=>600, 'colsNum' => 2);
    $section = $PHPWord->createSection($sectionStyle);

    // Define table style arrays
    $styleTable = array('borderSize'=>6, 'borderColor'=>'006699', 'cellMargin'=>80, 'width'=>100);

    // Define font style for first row
    $fontStyle = array('bold'=>true, 'align'=>'center');

    // Add table style
    $PHPWord->addTableStyle('myOwnTableStyle', $styleTable);

    // Add table
    $table = $section->addTable('myOwnTableStyle');
```